# Is it possible to implement an async method in StructuredTool with from_function?

Tags: langchain, panel-pyviz

I am looking at the recent [blog post](https://blog.langchain.dev/structured-tools/)/ [docs](https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/modules/agents/agents/examples/structured_chat.html) for StructuredTool and understand that I could implement a class from BaseTool with `arun` method. Is this possible somehow using from_function? This is my very first tool and the full class implementation is a bit intimidating.

My goal is to adapt this streaming chat UI example to work with my own tool instead of the OpenAIChat model. Right now it is finding my tool, streaming the first step's response back, then I get a "tool does not support async" error back.
https://discourse.holoviz.org/t/stream-langchain-responses-in-textbox/5427/4

I can use the example "elevator" pitch request and that will run with no problem. So just looking for the most straightforward way to support similar token streaming as OpenAIChat model using my custom tool and STRUCTURED_CHAT_ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION agent.

Comment: After looking some more, I am wondering if I need 2 CallbackHandlers... one for the chat stream and another to watch the state of the agent for completion?

Comment: Did you try `StructuredTool.from_function(func=your_sync_function, coroutine=your_async_function)`?